# Why it's not possible to use Array Functions on Objects implementing the ArrayAccess interface

Tags: php, arrays, interface

I have this `obj` class from the php documentation:

```
class obj implements ArrayAccess {
    private $container = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->container = array(
            "one"   => 1,
            "two"   => 2,
            "three" => 3,
        );
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

now, when I try to use the in_array function like

```
$obj = new obj;
echo in_array('1', $obj);
```

I get an

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given
```

Shouldn't an object that implements ArrayAccess act like an actual Array?

Comment: imo, I suspect to do their magic, the PHP `array_*` functions use the internal structures of the `array`. Whatever, Most of the time when I implement a class that implements the `array` interfaces, I extend `ArrayObject` or use an array internally. So, I always provide a method called `toArray()` and another method called `fromArray($array)` that do what you expect.  These are normally cheap to write as it just means returning the internal array I am using. That way I can still use them with the PHP `array_*` functions if required.

Comment: @RyanVincent the problem with this approach is if you're using a third-party package that expects to be able to directly use your object as an array.

Comment: @alexw, just curious, you have an example of such a third party package?

Comment: I'm currently trying to get an `ArrayAccess` object to work as my config service in Slim 3: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Container.php#L95-L97.  It uses `array_merge` to combine user settings (expected to be an array) with default settings.

Comment: @alexw, Well, obviously, you cannot pass your config object via the settings. That is ok as I assume that you want to use your config instead of the settings array anyway. I will use this example: [Accessing services in Slim 3](https://akrabat.com/accessing-services-in-slim-3/). I don't use slim but I do use Pimple :). You need to add an entry for your config: i.e.. $container['config'] = function ($container) { return new Configula\Config(APP_CONFIG_ROOT); }; I use config class http://github.com/caseyamcl/Configula. Also see [Application Bootstrap - config](http://pastebin.com/WTNvtcgH).

Comment: @RyanVincent this is basically what I ended up doing.  It seems silly to have two separate places to store configuration, but it might be the best solution.  I get what you're saying - if I try to `array_merge` my `Config` object with a native array, the function would have to either return an array (thus losing the benefits of my object), or return a `Config` object (in which case it would have to know how to construct the new object and somehow retain the interesting properties of the original object).